# What is the attribute type of my sql time period

Tags: mysql, date, attributes, sqldatatypes

In my my sql table I have start_date, end_date, and time_period(the gap between start_date and end_date/end_date-start_date)

I created attribute type as date in my start_date and end_date.

But I'm confused with attribute type of time_period

Which type most suitable for time_period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, we use an integer(int or bigint denpending on your time precision) to store time period.

[TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) returns the difference of two time value as an integer. You can specify the time precision via the first argument.

If you need another form, [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) returns the difference of two time value as a time value.

In this case, I would suggest you not to store a redundant time period in your table as you already stored the start and end time separately. You can easily get the time period via functions posted above whenever you need.

For more information, please read the [Date and Time Functions list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).